# Uniqueness of a solution to an IVP over a large domain

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

[image]

I get that both $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ are continuous on $I$ as they are differentiable on $I$ as they are solutions to the differential equation. However I do not understand why their continuity implies what is written in green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuity implies
$$x_1(b)=\lim_{t\to b^-}x_1(t)=\lim_{t\to b^-}x_2(t)=x_2(b)$$
First equality is due to the continuity of $x_1$, second due to $x_1(t)=x_2(t)$ for $t\in [0,b)$, and third equality is due to continuity of $x_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Or to write it without limits: $d(t)=\|x_1(t)-x_2(t)\|$ is a continuous function, thus the pre-image $d^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed.